# tqdm not refreshing postfix after last iteration

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, progress-bar, tqdm

I have the following code:

```
for epoch in range(start_epoch, end_epoch):
    train_loss = 0.0

    # Define training progress bar
    train_pbar = tqdm(train_dataloader, desc=f"Epoch {epoch}/{end_epoch}")

    for inputs, targets in train_pbar:
        # Do something ...

        train_pbar.set_postfix({"Train Loss": f"{item.loss:.4f}"})

    # Compute average training loss for this epoch
    train_loss /= len(train_dataloader)
    train_pbar.set_postfix({"Avg. Train Loss": f"{train_loss:.4f}"})
```

I'm trying to make it update the tqdm postfix in the end with the "Avg. Train Loss". However, it only shows the last "Train Loss" postfix from `train_pbar.set_postfix({"Train Loss": f"{item.loss:.4f}"})`. It is like `train_pbar.set_postfix({"Avg. Train Loss": f"{train_loss:.4f}"})`is not being executed... but it is.

The current output looks like this:

```
Epoch 0/1000: 100%|██████████| 30/30 [08:25<00:00, 16.85s/it, **Train Loss=5.1223**]

Validating: 100%|█████████████| 4/4 [01:04<00:00, 16.06s/it, **Val Loss=4.3432**]

Epoch 1/1000: 100%|██████████| 30/30 [08:21<00:00, 16.71s/it, **Train Loss=4.9234**]

Validating: 100%|██████████████| 4/4 [01:05<00:00, 16.39s/it, **Val Loss=5.0432**]

Epoch 2/1000:  20%|███████████| 6/30 [01:43<06:40, 16.69s/it, **Train Loss=5.4332**]

But I want it to look like:

Epoch 0/1000: 100%|███████| 30/30 [08:25<00:00, 16.85s/it, **Avg. Train Loss=5.1223**]

Validating: 100%|███████████| 4/4 [01:04<00:00, 16.06s/it, **Avg. Val Loss=4.3432**]

Epoch 1/1000: 100%|███████| 30/30 [08:21<00:00, 16.71s/it, **Avg. Train Loss=4.9234**]

Validating: 100%|███████████| 4/4 [01:05<00:00, 16.39s/it, **Avg. Val Loss=5.0432**]

Epoch 2/1000:  20%|███████████| 6/30 [01:43<06:40, 16.69s/it, **Train Loss=5.4332**]
```

So after the epoch ends the progress bar is updated with the average loss instead.